# Selenium project build failure with android studio

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-studio, appium

I'm learning QA and i got those errors and i can't seem to find a solution

```
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.remote.session.CapabilitiesFilter.apply(java.lang.Object)

    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities.getBrowserName() 

    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService$ThrowingSupplier.get()   

        Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.Object org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput$VoidCallable.call()    

    Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)    
    InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.  
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void com.google.common.collect.RangeSet.addAll(java.lang.Iterable) 
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Set com.google.common.collect.RowSortedTable.rowKeySet() 
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Collection com.google.common.collect.BiMap.values()  
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.util.Collection com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap.get(java.lang.Object)  
    Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): boolean com.google.common.base.Predicate.test(java.lang.Object)    
    null    
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Pierre Abi Chacra\Desktop\androidwidget\AppiumTest\app\libs\client-combined-3.12.0.jar    
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.  
    com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
    com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
```

This is my code :

```
 package com.example.pierreabichacra.appiumtest;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



    public class FirstTest {

        WebDriver driver;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
            // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            // Set android deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XT1562");

            // Set BROWSER_NAME desired capability. It's Android in our case here.
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");

            // Set android VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device's OS version.
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1.0");

            // Set android platformName desired capability. It's Android in our case here.
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

            // Set android appPackage desired capability. It is
            // com.android.calculator2 for calculator application.
            // Set your application's appPackage if you are using any other app.
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");

            // Set android appActivity desired capability. It is
            // com.android.calculator2.Calculator for calculator application.
            // Set your application's appPackage if you are using any other app.
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

            // Created object of RemoteWebDriver will all set capabilities.
            // Set appium server address and port number in URL string.
            // It will launch calculator app in android device.
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        }

        @Test
        public void testFirstCalculator() {



            // Click on DELETE/CLR button to clear result text box before running test.
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).get(0).click();

            // Click on number 2 button.
            driver.findElement(By.name("7")).click();

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @After
        public void End() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }


my gradle: 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pierreabichacra.appiumtest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.12.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.12.0-sources.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-23.6-jre.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.9.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your gradle will solve the issue:

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512629/android-studio-error-default-interface-methods-are-only-supported-starting-with/49525685): changing to 1.8 resolved the issue but i'll have to check it on older devices.